# Make sure current focus isn't textbox?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I'm working on an application in Flex 3.2, and I need to be able to tell whether the current focus is a textbox or not. How would I go about doing this? There's more than one textbox in my application, so I can't really set multiple event handlers for focusOut, etc.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: `stage.focus` holds the object that is the current focus.  `if(stage.focus is TextField)` should work. Though you may need to experiment and propagate up the focus display hierarchy to see if it's a child of a text box

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices How would I do that? `stage.focus.parent is TextField`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the `stage.focus` property.  It holds the instance of whatever object has the focus.

So in whatever spot you want to do the check, just do this:

```
if(stage.focus is TextField){
    //do whatever you'd like to do
}
```

I'm not really a flex user, but I'm pretty sure the text components use TextFields inside them and that the focus will still be a TextField class.  Someone please correct me if I'm mistaken.